# Scale image to fit text boxes around borders

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following plot in Matlab:

[image: Plot with text labels at top and left]

The image size may vary, and so may the length of the text boxes at the top and left.  I dynamically determine the strings that go in these text boxes and then create them with:

```
[M,N] = size(img);
imagesc((1:N)-0.5,(1:M)-0.5, img > 0.5); axis image; grid on;
colormap([1 1 1; 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
set(gca,'XColor','k','YColor','k','TickDir','out')
set(gca,'XTick',1:N,'XTickLabel',cell(1,N))
set(gca,'YTick',1:N,'YTickLabel',cell(1,N))

for iter = 1:M
    text(-0.5, iter-0.5, sprintf(strL, br{iter,:}), ...
         'FontSize',16, ...
         'HorizontalAlignment','right', ...
         'VerticalAlignment','middle', ...
         'Interpreter','latex' );
end

for iter = 1:N
    text(iter-0.5, -0.5, {bc{:,iter}}, ...
         'FontSize',16, ...
         'HorizontalAlignment','center', ...
         'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
         'Interpreter','latex' );
end
```

where `br` and `bc` are cell arrays containing the appropriate numbers for the labels. The problem is that most of the time, the text gets clipped by the edges of the figure.  I am using this as a workaround:

```
set(gca,'Position',[0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5]);
```

As you can see, I am simply adding a larger border around the plot so that there is more room for the text.  While this scaling works for one zoom level, if I maximize my plot window I get way too much empty space, and if I shrink my plot window, I get clipping again.  Is there a more intelligent way to add these labels to use the minimum amount of space while making sure that the text does not get clipped?

**Edit:**

I have tried the [TextZoomable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41513-textzoomable-for-text-that-scales-as-you-zoom) package recommended by Bas Swinckels and it helps out a lot with the zooming problems, but I still have to use the `set(gca,'Position',[0.25 0.25 0.5 0.5])` workaround in order to fit the zoomable text.  This is less than ideal because I still get clipping when the string is too long.  I am still interested in finding a solution in which I can guarantee that the text does not clip.  From there I can use TextZoomable if I want to prevent clipping as the figure is scaled.

Comment: Positioning of axes is not Matlab's strongest point. For a real solution, you should probably calculate your axis's position based on the length of the labels. For a lazy solution, just make a large space and chop off the whitespace with an image editor. But these puzzles are fun, I once wrote some solver in python ...

Comment: I don't mind doing it the hard way, I am just having trouble understanding how to go about it. The problem that I keep running into is that when I resize my figure, the image scaling changes, but the text scaling doesn't. Do I have to hook into the figure resizing function somehow in order to compute my new plot size every time the figure position/size changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want that your text scales when you move/zoom/stretch the image. You might have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41513-textzoomable-for-text-that-scales-as-you-zoom) solution on the file-exchange. I haven't used it myself, so I don't know if you can use it as is. But maybe the source code can give you some inspiration for a solution.

Comment: The `TextZoomable` package actually works surprisingly well, and I was able to just replace my calls to `text` with calls to `TextZoomable` without making any other changes!

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't achieve exactly what I'm after (see the edit to my question) I am marking it as the answer, since it is the best answer offered. :)